# Why won't my c# connection string to a SQL server work with Windows authentication?

Tags: c#, sql

Why won't my connection string to SQL server work with Windows authentication? A sql user works fine, acme\administrator or administrator@acme.com won't work. This is a Win Form app written in C#.

```
    {
        OdbcConnection cn = null;
        String connectionString;
            connectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" + cbxDataSources.Text +";Database=" + strDatabase + ";";

            connectionString += "UID=" + textBoxUserName.Text + ";";
            connectionString += "PWD=" + textBoxPassword.Text + ";";

        cn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
        return cn;
    }
```

Thanks guys

Comment: I like this site a lot for helping out with these types of questions:
http://www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 15):

You are using SQL Server authentication.

Windows authentication authenticates your connection with the Windows identity of the currently executing process or thread. You cannot set a username and password with Windows authentication. Instead, you set Integrated Security = SSPI.

Answer (score 7):

You have to connect using a Trusted Connection.

2005:

```
Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

2000:

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```